# Visual studio 2013 & 2015 localhost not responding

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

First time user of visual studio.  running simple project web asp.net empty web application. create html 5 page and when I click on run, the browser comes up and just says waiting for localhost.  I have mysql running and can connect to it on localhost without any problems.  Clean install of visual studio on windows 10.

Also, when I view in browser from VS get same response - waiting for localhost.  Works fine if I open the file outside of VS.  No break points and IPv6 disabled

Comment: Do you have any breakpoints set that it is stopping on?

Comment: no breakpoints and IPv6 disabled

Comment: Does it just time out? I find load issues like these usually have to do with a bad web.config or global.asax.cs\startup.cs. Have you tried updating your nuget packages?

Answer (score 1):

you may have this error during the debug mode in VS 2013 or 2015. devExpress forum has . 
[a great discussion](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T142641) here.
simply speaking, just turn off the option Enable Browser Link (the little refresh icon besides Internet Explorer button).

Hope this helps.